# can't deserialize xml file into model

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I've got an XML file that represents movies and their categories. Each category has a list of movies. All I'm trying to do is to deserialize this file and pass this into a Model to consume. I've used the XMLRoot and XMLElement tags as described in similar threads with this same error but to no avail.

the debugger stops on

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MovieList));
```

with "`There is an error in XML document (2, 2)`".

I'm still learning. My guess is the XML attribute tags are misplaced.

XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
 <categories  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <category>
           <id>1</id>
           <description>action</description>
           <movies>
                <movie>
                     <id>1</id>
                     <name>The Dark Knight</name>
                </movie>
                <movie>
                     <id>2</id>
                     <name>Iron Man</name>
                </movie>
           </movies>
      </category>
      <category>
           <id>2</id>
           <description>comedy</description>
           <movies>
                <movie>
                     <id>1</id>
                     <name>Harold and Kumar</name>
                </movie>
                <movie>
                     <id>2</id>
                     <name>Knocked Up</name>
                </movie>
           </movies>
      </category>
  </categories>
```

Model

```
 XmlRoot("categories")]
 public class MovieList
 {
      [XmlElement("category")]
      public int id { get; set; }
      public string description { get; set; }
      public List<Movie> movies { get; set; }
 }

 public class Movie
 {
      public int id { get; set; }
      public string name { get; set; }
 }
```

Method

```
 public static MovieList Deserialize()
 {
  using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader("c:\\movies.xml"))
  {
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MovieList));
    return (MovieList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you try this: XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MovieList>));

Comment: it's actually giving me the same error